# Filtering CardView with RecyclerView, not updating cards, always showing first cards

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

I'm using a Cardview to populate my recyclerview.

I'm filtering with an EditText field, this works fine I know from debugging.

The problem is, when I call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` the top cards stay. (depending on how many cards got through the filter)

My 4 strings i'm filtering on are

```
Antwerpen
Deinze
Gent
Edegem
```

On the image you can see that with `"ge"` there are 2 cards, but only the 2 top ones.. not the correct strings.

I've fiddled around with `container.removeAllViewsInLayout();`in my fragment but I'm not sure where to implement it. I did this in the `OnCreateViewHolder` before the `layoutInflater` but then the filter works but the cards are not well shown.

[image]

UPDATE

I've implemented the answer given by Jeffalee, thank you for responding!

But no luck, got still the same problem, I'll post my code below.

ADAPTER:

```
public class GemeenteAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<GemeenteAdapter.GemeenteViewHolder> {

    private List<Gemeente> gemeentes;
    private List<Gemeente> filteredList;


    public GemeenteAdapter(List<Gemeente> gemeentes, List<Gemeente> original) {
        this.gemeentes = gemeentes;
        filteredList = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        if (isFilterActive) {
            return filteredList.size();
        } else {
            return gemeentes.size();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(GemeenteAdapter.GemeenteViewHolder holder, int i) {
        Gemeente gemeente;
        if (isFilterActive) {
            gemeente = filteredList.get(i);
        } else {
            gemeente = gemeentes.get(i);
        }
        GemeenteViewHolder.vNaam.setText(gemeente.naam);
    }


    @Override
    public GemeenteViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.fragment_cardview_small, viewGroup, false);
        return new GemeenteViewHolder(v);
    }


    public static class GemeenteViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        protected static TextView vNaam;
        public GemeenteViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            vNaam = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txtNaam);
        }
    }


    /**
     * FILTER TEST 2
     */

    boolean isFilterActive = false;

    public void setFilter(String searchCriteria) {

        setFilteredItems(searchCriteria);
        isFilterActive = true;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void clearFilter() {
        isFilterActive = false;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    private void setFilteredItems(String searchCriteria) {
        System.out.println(searchCriteria);
        for (Gemeente item : gemeentes) {
            if (item.getNaam().toLowerCase().trim().contains(searchCriteria.toLowerCase())) {
                System.out.println(item.getNaam());
                filteredList.add(item);
            }
        }
    }
```

FRAGMENT:

```
public class FragmentSearch extends Fragment {
    //Methode om de fragment te initializeren
    public static FragmentSearch newInstance() {
        FragmentSearch fragment = new FragmentSearch();
        return fragment;
    }

    public FragmentSearch() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_recycler_gemeente, container, false);
        Context context = getActivity();
        RecyclerView rv = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.cardList);

        rv.setHasFixedSize(true);


        LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(context);
        llm.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
        rv.setLayoutManager(llm);

        Gemeente gemeente = new Gemeente();
        final GemeenteAdapter adapter = new GemeenteAdapter(gemeente.init(),gemeente.init());

        rv.setAdapter(adapter);

        /**
         * Set filter when text is changed in EditText
         */
        final EditText yourEditText = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.edittext);

        yourEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            }


            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                adapter.setFilter(yourEditText.getText().toString());


            }
        });
        return view;
    }
```

I hope this gives you guys some more info.

Comment: Hi, did you ever get your issue resolved?  If so, can you please advise on your solution?  I am facing a similar issue.

Answer (score 2):

What happens is that there are two results for the searchcriteria 'ge', Gent and Edegem. You set the count of your `Adapter` to the right amount (2 in this case). But in your `onBindViewHolder()` method you forgot to take the position of the filtered `List` of items. What I usually do to filter a `RecyclerView` is the following.

**Step 1:** Create a custom `Adapter` for your `RecyclerView` (I assume you already did this)

**Step 2:** Create a second `List` of items (I assume you're using an `ArrayList` of `String`s), which will be filled with the items matching the searchcriteria ('ge' in this example) and a `boolean` which will keep track if the `Adapter` should use the filtered `List` or the non-filtered `List`

```
    List<String> items = new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> filteredItems = new ArrayList<>();
    boolean isFilterActive = false;
```

**Step 3:** Create a `setFilter(String searchCriteria)` and `clearFilter()` method in your custom adapter like this:

```
    public void setFilter(String searchCriteria) {
        setFilteredItems(searchCriteria);
        isFilterActive = true;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void clearFilter() {
        isFilterActive = false;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    private void setFilteredItems(String searchCriteria) {
        for(String item: items) {
            if(item.toLowerCase().contains(searchCriteria.toLowerCase())) {
                filteredItems.add(item);
            }
        }
    }
```

**Step 4:** Return the proper itemcount and the proper item at each position. To return the proper amount for the filtered items, just use this:

```
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        if(isFilterActive) {
            return filteredItems.size();
        } else {
            return items.size();
        }
    }
```

And to get the right items to show in your RecyclerView use this:

```
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        String item;
        if (isFilterActive) {
            item = filteredItems.get(position);
        } else {
            item = items.get(position);
        }

        //TODO set the value of 'item' to your TextView
    }
```

**Step 5:** Call the filter methods. When needed, you can simply get the Adapter from your RecyclerView and then call the set/clear filter methods (after casting it to your custom `Adapter` class) like this:

```
      MyCustomAdapter adapter = (MyCustomAdapter) myRecyclerView.getAdapter();
      adapter.setFilter("ge");
```

or

```
      adapter.clearFilter();
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi Jeffalee, thanks for answering, I've implemented your code with no luck. I've also updated my question with my code. I feel that I'm missing something small, and as usual, small things could give big headaches..